# How to know if a Visual Studio project item is a WebReference?

Tags: c#, .net, vsx, vs-extensibility, vspackage

I'm developing a Visual Studio extensibility package. I need to get the files under a project hierarchy using [`IVsSccProject2.GetSccFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssccproject2.getsccfiles.aspx).

Visual Studio behaves different for an standard folders and for WebReferences:

- An standard folder returns no SCC files even it has childs.
- The WebReference returns all the files under the web reference (*.wsdl, *.datasource, *.map, *.cs)

This causes a problem because I use a common function to enumerate files under a project item.

How can I determine if the project item is a web reference or a standard folder?

I tried to get the item type using:

```
hierProject.GetGuidProperty(
    itemid,
    (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_TypeGuid,
    out guid);
```

but in this case the [returned GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4bcch80%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is always Physical Folder (`6BB5F8EF-4483-11D3-8BCF-00C04F8EC28C`) for both WebReference and standard folder.

Comment: I wonder if GetSccSpecialFiles might give you a better hint for a web service node?

Comment: @Russ C: What do you mean exactly? Grrr, no doc about GetSccSpecialFiles flags. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssccproject2.getsccspecialfiles(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: The GetSccFiles has a sister method, GetSccSpecialFiles - I thought it might be worth perusing the results.

Comment: @Russ C: You have answered my question. If its a Physical Folder and has special files, I will not have them into account. Thanks!!

Comment: Brilliant, I'll add that as an answer if that's ok :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments above, use the GetSccSpecialFiles method.